# created PS_script which for know the free IP and CIDR in exacting Vnet in Azure but getting error

Tags: powershell, shell, ui-automation, azure-powershell

While executing the powershell script for check avaiable free IP address with CIDR in exacting Vnet in Azure but getting failed as per below SS error.

```
# Connect to your Azure account (if not already connected)
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription xyz-sub
# Define the Azure resource group and virtual network name
$resourceGroupName = "network-01-rg"
$virtualNetworkName = "network-01-vnet"

# Get the virtual network object
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $virtualNetworkName

# Check if the virtual network exists
if (!$virtualNetwork) {
    Write-Host "Virtual network '$virtualNetworkName' not found in resource group '$resourceGroupName'."
    return
}

# Function to find a free IP CIDR range in a given subnet
function Get-FreeIPCIDRRange {
    param (
        [string]$subnetAddressPrefix,
        [array]$existingSubnets
    )
    $subnetCIDR = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($subnetAddressPrefix).GetAddressBytes()
    $subnetBits = $subnetAddressPrefix.Split("/")[1]
    foreach ($existingSubnet in $existingSubnets) {
        $existingCIDR = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($existingSubnet.AddressPrefix).GetAddressBytes()
        $existingBits = $existingSubnet.AddressPrefix.Split("/")[0]
        # Calculate the number of addresses in each subnet
        $totalAddresses = [System.Math]::Pow(2, 32 - $existingBits)
        # Calculate the first address of the existing subnet
        $existingStartAddress = $existingCIDR[0] -band ([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast -bxor ([System.Math]::Pow(2, 32) - [System.Math]::Pow(2, 32 - $existingBits)))
        # Calculate the last address of the existing subnet
        $existingEndAddress = $existingStartAddress + $totalAddresses - 1
        # Calculate the first address of the new subnet
        $newStartAddress = $subnetCIDR[0] -band ([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast -bxor ([System.Math]::Pow(2, 32) - [System.Math]::Pow(2, 32 - $subnetBits)))
        # If the new subnet's first address is greater than the existing subnet's last address, the range is free
        if ($newStartAddress -gt $existingEndAddress) {
            return $subnetAddressPrefix
        }
    }
    return $null
}
# Retrieve the existing subnets in the virtual network
$existingSubnets = $virtualNetwork.Subnets
# Find a free IP CIDR range for the new subnet
$availableCIDR = $null
for ($i = 32; $i -le 29; $i++) {
    $proposedCIDR = "172.28.$i.0/$i"
    $availableCIDR = Get-FreeIPCIDRRange -subnetAddressPrefix $proposedCIDR -existingSubnets $existingSubnets

    if ($availableCIDR -ne $null) {
        break
    }
}
# Check if a free IP CIDR range was found
if ($availableCIDR -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "A free IP CIDR range is available: $availableCIDR"
}
else {
    Write-Host "No free IP CIDR range is available in the virtual network '$virtualNetworkName'."
}
```

Error:-
Script Output
[image: error screenshot]

As per the output we need someware define varibale as an IP address? (In the place of [System.Net.IPAddress])

Manual screenshot for reference:-
[image: https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html]

with script actually i want to know the free avaibale IP address with CIDR in exacting Vnet? (let say a new requiement are come in my project for create new subnet in exacting Vnet with IP address 172.28.x.x/25 so these thing now we are doing manually with attached url link https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html) and now i want to do automatically with help of script

Comment: Only look at first error.  Others are due to first error returning no data.  Is the port number the same as the IP? "172.28.$i.0/$i"  The number after the forward slash is the port number.

Comment: @jdweng no, not this is port numbet these are ip's like 10.6.0.0/24, after forward slash 24 is the subnet mask.

Comment: A 24 bit mask is 255.255.255.0.  Still why are you using the IP segment and the mask size as the same number 172.28.24.0/24. suppose $i = 40?  It would be 172.28.40.0/40 Masks cannot be greater than 32.

Comment: @jdweng 
# Retrieve the existing subnets in the virtual network
$existingSubnets = $virtualNetwork.Subnets
# Find a free IP CIDR range for the new subnet
$availableCIDR = $null
for ($i = 32; $i -le 29; $i++) {
    $proposedCIDR = "172.28.$i.0/$i"
    $availableCIDR = Get-FreeIPCIDRRange -subnetAddressPrefix $proposedCIDR -existingSubnets $existingSubnets

    if ($availableCIDR -ne $null) {
        break
    }
}
# Check if a free IP CIDR range was found
if ($availableCIDR -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "A free IP CIDR range is available: $availableCIDR"
}
else {

Comment: @jdweng Thansk for your reply, know that the subnet should not be grater then 32,as above i given the value of varibale $i after that executong the script output is getting "No free IP CIDR range is available in the virtual network 'network-01-vnet" so what value should i passed to know that xyz CIDR is free in my exacting vnet subnet use.

Comment: The IP address assigned to the Azure VM has to be within the range of addresses of your intranet.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses?tabs=nic-address-portal  Using ARP -A will give a list of IP addresses being used by your network.  Then you can assign an IP in your subnet.  See : https://www.digi.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-use-arp-ping-to-assign-an-ip-address-to-por  The ARP table is a list of IP addresses that were seen recently by you intranet.

Comment: @jdweng thansk for sharing above URL really this was very helpful. i think hope-so you not get much cleared with my above question/script actually i want to know the free avaibale IP address with CIDR in exacting Vnet? (let say a new requiement are come in my project for create new subnet in exacting Vnet with 172.28.x.x/25 so these thing now we are doing with help of this url) and now i want to do automatically with help of script https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html (now manually i used this url for deviding with one ip/cidr subnet to multiple ip/cider subnet

Comment: The error message you’ve posted is because ```System.Net.IPAddress.Parse``` doesn’t understand CIDR ranges - see the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.parse?view=net-7.0 which says the ```ipString``` parameter is “A string that contains an IP address in dotted-quad notation for IPv4 and in colon-hexadecimal notation for IPv6”.  You can reproduce the error with simply ```[System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("10.0.0.0/24")```. Not sure how that fits in with the rest of your goal, but that’s the root cause of the initial error…

Comment: An IP is a uint (4 bytes) with each field being a byte (0 to FF or 0 to 255). So 172.28.X.X is 0xAC1C0000.  The only way of telling for sure if an address is used is to make a table of assigned IP.  Doing a ping will only work if a device is turned on.